# How to combine two state variable in one input

Tags: reactjs

inputValue contains inputValue.latitude and inputValue.longitude.
How to make it display as a value of one input?

```
 const [inputValue, setInputValue] = useState('')

 <input value={here I need to display inputValue.latitude and 
               inputValue.longitude } />
```

Comment: You'll need to give more detail on what you're actually after.. You can just concatenate them `inputValue.latitude + ' ' + inputValue.longitude`, but that doesn't seem very helpful for an input.. What are you actually trying to achieve? Why does it need to be a single input for two distinct values?

Answer (score 2):

First the default state of the `useState` should use the same squema.

```
const [inputValue, setInputValue] = useState({ latitude: "", longitude: "" });
```

For the input, you could use separete inputs for each value and show the concatenation in another one but this one disabled.

```
return (
    <>
        <input value={inputValue.latitude} onChange={(e) => setInputValue(values => ({ ...values, latitude: e.target.value }))} />
        <input value={inputValue.longitude} onChange={(e) => setInputValue(values => ({ ...values, longitude: e.target.value }))} />
        <input value={`${inputValue.longitude} ${inputValue.latitude}`} disabled />
    </>
)
```